# Can I create and object that "self-loads" properties from a data source?

Tags: c#, json, design-patterns

I have a design pattern question that I'm hoping you can help me with.

I have a C# application that stores objects in a database as JSON. Currently, a dedicated class handles loading the JSON, deserializing, and returning the object. This works great, but I'm wondering if there is an approach that would allow the object to "self-load" (for lack of a better term).

What I am doing now is (short-hand code):

```
public class MyObject {
    public string Name;
    public string Rank;
    public int SerialNo;
}

public class DataTransport{
   public MyObject LoadMyObject(string ObjectId){
       string ObjectJSON = fetch.from.database;
       return ObjectJSON.deserialize.object;
   }
}

DataTransport dt = new DataTransport();
MyObject mo = dt.LoadMyObject("object123");
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
public class MyObject {
    public string Name;
    public string Rank;
    public int SerialNo;
    public MyObject(string ObjectId){
       DataTransport dt = new DataTransport();
       this = dt.LoadMyObject(ObjectId);
    }
}

MyObject mo = new MyObject("object123);
```

Obviously this fails, but is there a similar mechanism to have the constructor replace itself with the object loaded from the database?

I've thought about loading and manually assigning properties when instantiated, but that risk and hassle doesn't pass the cost/benefit smell test.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Look into either the ValueInjecter or AutoMapper packages (I prefer ValueInjecter myself because it requires less manual setup): https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter and https://automapper.org/

Comment: You could but it all comes down to as a matter of opinion whether you think an object should be responsible for loading itself? I shall leave it to you.   If you did, static code analysis would show that you would be tightly-coupling your class to the particular type of class that does the actual loading.  You could somewhat de-couple it by injecting say a `IDataTransport`.

Answer (score 0):

You could essentially do what you want if you made your `LoadMyObject()` method populate an existing object instance from the JSON instead of creating a new one.  Maybe `PopulateMyObject()` would be a better name for it:

```
public void PopulateMyObject(string ObjectId, object target)
{
    string ObjectJSON = FetchJsonFromDatabase(ObjectId);
    PopulateObjectFromJson(ObjectJSON, target);
}
```

Incidentally, [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) supports populating existing objects from JSON out of the box, so you could use its `JsonConvert.PopulateObject` method as a drop-in replacement for `PopulateObjectFromJson` in the above code.

Then in your object constructors you just do:

```
public MyObject(string ObjectId)
{
    DataTransport dt = new DataTransport();
    dt.PopulateMyObject(ObjectId, this);
}
```

Concept fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9bHeN

Of course, @MickyD makes a very good point in the comments that you would be tightly coupling all your model objects to the `DataTransport` object, which may not be desirable.